# Parallel structure

Tags: conjunctions

As the rule says both side of 'and' should have same form to make a balanced or parallel sentence but I am confused of following case:

> Jodie and I went to market.

Here Jodie is proper noun but I is pronoun though is it a justified sentence?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a pronoun is a word that takes the place of a noun, so you can use it wherever you are supposed to use a noun, as long as the *case of the noun* makes sense.

For example, you have to use subject pronouns for a sentence's subject, and object pronouns where an object is expected, and possessive pronouns if you are expressing possession.

So your example is fine.